# Modify and return list of maps with get_and_update Elixir

Tags: elixir

So my goal is to take a list of maps, such as:

```
[%{"ts" => 1365111111, "url" => "http://example1.com"}, %{"ts" => 1365111115, "url" => "http://example2.com"}]
```

convert the unix timestamp value for the `ts` key using the [DateTime module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_unix!/3)
and return a new collection of the maps:

```
[%{"ts" => #DateTime<2013-04-04 21:31:51Z>, "url" => "http://example1.com"},%{"ts" => #DateTime<2013-04-04 21:31:51Z>, "url" => "http://example2.com"}]
```

So I tried using [`get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get_and_update/3) like this:

```
merge_maps =  [%{"ts" => 1365111111, "url" => "http://example1.com"}, %{"ts" => 1365111115, "url" => "http://example2.com"}]

new_maps = Enum.map(merge_maps, fn elem ->
  Map.get_and_update!(elem, "ts", fn curr_value ->
    {curr_value, curr_value |> DateTime.from_unix!} end)
end)
```

How can I return the list of modified maps in `new_maps` instead of what is currently returned which is a list of tuples:

```
[       
  {1365111111,
   %{"ts" => #DateTime<2013-04-04 21:31:51Z>, "url" => "http://mandrill.com"}},
  {1365111111, %{"ts" => #DateTime<2013-04-04 21:31:51Z>}}
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need here is `Map.update!/3`, not `Map.get_and_update/3`:

```
new_maps = Enum.map(merge_maps, fn elem ->
  Map.update!(elem, "ts", fn curr_value -> curr_value |> DateTime.from_unix! end)
end)
```

or just

```
new_maps = Enum.map(merge_maps, fn elem ->
  Map.update!(elem, "ts", &DateTime.from_unix!/1)
end)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. so the `get_and_update` basically update the record and return also the old one in a tuple? I prefer the second example :))

Comment: Yes, it returns a tuple of the first value returned by the function and the map updated with the second value returned by the function.